# Should I make a unittest for all the classes with the same method/functionality?

Tags: c#

I have many classes containing the same methods. Each class implements its own interface and the reason for that is because I need a seperate instance for each class. Each class has its own lock(locks the instance of the class where it will not allow another call to disturb the critical section) and the process will be repeated again and again eg.

```
`public interface IClassA
{
CommonMethod1();
CommonMethod2();
...
}

public class ClassA: IClassA
{
// implementation
}

public interface IClassB
{
CommonMethod1();
CommonMethod2();
}

public class ClassB: IClassB
{
// implementation
}


// add singleton
services.AddSingleton<IClassA>, ClassA>();
services.AddSingleton<IClassB>, ClassB>();`
```

I have been told that "making interfaces for each class will ease the process. Inheritance and abstraction will not be a good option with the singleton". My question is:

1. Is there any better solution to reduce the duplication of code by having an instance for each class?
2. If yes, How will automation test work?
3. If No, should I make a unittest for each class?

Hopefully it makes sense otherwise please ask if there should be any confusion :)

I will appreciate, if i get a better solution :)

Comment: Is `IClassA` the same as `IClassB` and they have same methods?

Comment: If you need different implementations for the same interface by some sort of additional context information this shouts "factory pattern".

Comment: But for tests you test concrete implementations and not interfaces.. So if you have multiple implermentations you need to test for all of them but the concrete implementation might be an input to the concrete tests so you don't have to write the same thing multiple times.

Comment: Yes, they are the same and the reason why I have interfaces for each class is because of dependency injection and singleton

Comment: Implementations are the same. Can I use factory pattern without using new keywords? There should be only one instance of a class